# How to Bind callback functions using pybind11

Tags: pybind11

We have the following callback in C which I need to bind it using pybind11 so that, it can be called from python.

```
typedef gpointer (*CopyFunc) (gpointer data, gpointer user_data);
```

then We have a structure that uses the above-defined callback as follows

```
struct _DATA{
  int element_size;
  int num_empty_elements;
  CopyFunc copy_func;
}DATA;
```

Currently, we have binded them using the following approach. First we register the callback as follows

```
std::function<gpointer(gpointer,gpointer)> g_copyfunc;

static void register_copyfunc(std::function<gpointer(gpointer,gpointer)> const& func)
{
    g_copyfunc = func;
}
```

then we call this register callback as follows

```
static gpointer copyfunc_wrapper(gpointer arg1, gpointer arg2)
{
    return g_copyfunc(arg1, arg2);
}
```

from python we pass the callback function using bindings to register the function as follows

```
 m.def("register_copyfunc",
            [](std::function<COPYFUNC_SIG> const& func) {
            register_copyfunc(func);
        });
```

then we set the function to the structure element as follows

```
m.def("set_user_copyfunc",
        [](DATA *data, std::function<COPYFUNC_SIG> const& func) {
            data->copy_func = (CopyFunc) copyfunc_wrapper;
        });
```

Is there any approach within pybind11 to bind this callback without following the above hack?